# In the listings package, is it possible to highlight special characters like curly braces similarly to keywords?

Tags: listings

I am writing a Latex article that contains some [Typed Lua](https://github.com/andremm/typedlua) code snippets. They look like regular Lua code but have some additional type annotations. For example, something like this:

```
function newlist(): {integer}
    local xs = {}
    for i = 1, 10 do
        xs[i] = 42
    end
    return xs
end
```

Is there a way for me to typeset that `: {integer}` type annotation in bold, or at least just the `{integer}` in bold? Bonus points if there is a way to do this without also highlighting the `{}` table constructor in the second line.

So far the best I managed was to define `integer` as an additional keyword but I think the end result looked weird when the `integer` was typeset differently from the curly braces that surround it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{TypedLua}[5.3]{Lua}{
    morekeywords={integer,float}
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=TypedLua}
\begin{lstlisting}
function newlist(): {integer}
    local xs = {}
    for i = 1, 10 do
        xs[i] = 42
    end
    return xs
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to highlight? `: {integer}` as a whole keyword? or patterns such as `: {*}`? Also, please add a MWE.

Comment: I would like to highlight `{integer}` and I do not want to highlight `{}`. Other things are less important and I don't care as much if they are highlighted or not. I would be OK with hard coded "dumb" rules. If necessary, I would also be OK with manually highlighting things in my program, without taking advantage of the "morekeywords" feature in the listings package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, depending on your needs.

1. Simple solution:

   `morekeywords={\{integer\}}`

   Though you'll need to force `listings` to consider curly braces as "letters" for this to work:

   `alsoletter={\{,\}}`
2. Perhaps better:

   `moredelim=[s][\bfseries]{:\ \{}{\}}`

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{TypedLua1}[5.3]{Lua}{
    morekeywords={\{integer\},float},
    alsoletter={\{,\}}
}
\lstdefinelanguage{TypedLua2}[5.3]{Lua}{
    moredelim=[s][\bfseries]{:\ \{}{\}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TypedLua1]
function newlist(): {integer}
    local xs = {}
    for i = 1, 10 do
        xs[i] = 42
    end
    return xs
end
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TypedLua2]
function newlist(): {integer}
    local xs = {}
    for i = 1, 10 do
        xs[i] = 42
    end
    return xs
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Two listings]

Comment: Thank you! The "alsoletter" was the crucial missing part for me.